# Reduce burning time for a toaster by changing resistor?

Tags: resistors

A good looking toaster still working, but I notice recently the bread slices went always too much brown/black even with the minimal time setting (stage 1). The time levels are set by a potentiometer, I thought I could change(parallel or serial) the resistor to reduce time. But after disassembled the toaster and unsoldered the potentiometer, I measured the resistance at stage 1 is 0 (Ω). But still gives 1'25" of toasting/burning time. (stage 6 for 2'50".) What can I do to reduce the burning time?

Many thanks for any advice.

Hereby I attached the photos of the PCB board. [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome. Questions about product repairs are off-limits on the SE websites. If you can diagnose the problem with a DVM / ohmmeter we might be able to send you on the right path.

Comment: start by obtaining a schematic diagram, either from the internet or drawing it yourself

Comment: Can you add the chip part numbers to your question, please?

Comment: Start the toaster, wait a few seconds, put the bread in and hey presto.

Comment: It should be very easy to trace out the circuit. | The CD4541 is a timer IC. The oscillator capacitor is on pin 2 unless its mains frequency dividing. [datasheet here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4541b.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1594898320529) With a circuit we can advise further. You could follow tracks or in most case set DMM to ohms bepper and probe between possibly connected points. You'll miss some. Then turn board over and complete. || Photocopy PCB copper side. Draw ICs on with numbers. It should start to come clear quite quickly.

Comment: And - congratulations on trying to fix something in this throwaway age. For interest - where are you located? (I'm in NZ)

Comment: Cmon @Andyaka we can fix it, we know we can. This is fun! :-) - Anyone trying to fix consumer equipment should be encouraged.

Comment: There is nothing to fix as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Andyaka It MAY need a mod rather than a fix - either way - if he provides the circuit - easily enough doable - we can assist him.

Comment: (1)  Ensure that the Bagel Defrost or Reheat buttons are not stuck on - this would alter the performance.  (2) Right next to the variable resistor (a "potentiometer" with two leads joined together) terminals is a resistor (MAY be R8?) - Brown Red Green = 1.2.0000 = 1.2 megohm. This is in series with the variable resistor. Parallel it with another resistor of ABOUT the same value (say a 1 megohm or 1.2 or ...). This will halve its effective value.  That should shorten the cooking time. ||

Comment: I'm interested in knowing how the resistor change affects things. What is the pot resistance?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: No mech. resistance while the move is free & clean. Once time is up, the relay magnetic kiss will be released, pot will be lifted up with the spring force pre-stressed (was against the magnetic force). just ordered/received Delongi 2103.GR, it seems time settings are globally fixed for each stage. Comparing the heat both toasters, the old seems much higher (both 900W), maybe something wrong with the heating PCB/system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)  Ensure that the Bagel, Defrost or Reheat buttons are not stuck on - this would alter the performance.

(2) Right next to the variable resistor (a "potentiometer" with two leads joined together) terminals is a resistor (MAY be R8?) - Brown Red Green = 1.2.0000 = 1.2 megohm. This is in series with the variable resistor. Parallel it with another resistor of ABOUT the same value (say a 1 megohm or 1.2 or ...). This will halve its effective value.  That should shorten the cooking time.

[image]

Comment: I will tried to find/order the spare parts, incl. the potentiometer (B100K?), come back to your solution later. many thanks!

Comment: My change is easy and cheap. The potentiometer can easily be tested, in or out of circuit. The top two contacts are joined so you should get a substantial change in R between middle and lower as the pot is turned. The 1M2 resistor will buffer the pot R from other cct R when measuring.

Answer (score 5):

There's not much on that board to go wrong, and it looks pretty old and like it's seen some relatively high temperatures.

Start by swapping out that electrolytic capacitor (the can bottom right) with a new one. Observe polarity(!)

While you're at it, examine the connections carefully to the pot to make sure that one of the pads has not lifted causing the time to be longer than expected. To do this look carefully at the solder blobs on the 3 pins (two are connected together) and **gently** push sideways on the pot shaft in various directions. Any motion at all relative to the board indicates a lifted pad (can be easily repaired by jumpering over it to a nearby pad with a few bits of bare wire). In fact you can do that pre-emptively.

[image]

These two things (aged electrolytic capacitors and mechanical damage- especially near mounting, heavy parts or user actuated components) amount for quite a few failures. Modern switching power supplies have a few more stressed parts so they can fail catastrophically in a few more places, but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: This is old phenolic board from 2002. It "cooks" much more than FR-4 will.

Comment: @Sparky256 I did quite a few designs with the lighter colored variant of that kind of board, punched holes and outlines, single-sided. Amazingly cheap and pretty good if you keep mechanical stresses off of it.

Comment: Thanks!   
 
 1)  Why change that capacitor(330uF/16V) could affect  time? i.e., what are the  normal/standard time settings for a toaster?  this one currently at stage 1: 1'25", stage 6: 2'50" ;

2) I thought I could change the ohms of potentiometer to influence the burning time, but I unsoldered it and took out, measured at the stage 1 it is already 0 (Ω), seem there's nothing can do to modify ohms?

3)  Mechanical malfunction or clean movement can be eliminated. Hereby time set by potentiometer driving the relay magnetic mechanism to release the lifter.

Comment: The capacitor is part of the power supply. Power supplies affect everything, huge amounts of ripple from a dried out capacitor will cause some kind of malfunction.

Comment: I will tried to find/order the spare parts, incl. the potentiometer (B100K?), come back to your advice later. thanks!